# Complex numbers- elementary question

Tags: complex-numbers

How can I calculate the argument of the complex number $z= (\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}) \cdot (1+i)$?

I always get $\tan^{-1}(-2-\sqrt{3})$, but the book answer is $7 \pi/12$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, or $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\,i$?

Comment: Look to my edited question

Comment: Aren't arguments additive.  So arg(1 + i) is clearly $\pi/4$ and arg(1/2 + root(3)/2 i) is clearly $\pi/3$ isn't the arg $\pi/4 + \pi/3 = 7\pi/12$?

Comment: Tarik, check my edit for your question.

Comment: By the way $\tan^{-1}(-2 - \sqrt{3}) = -5\pi/12 = 7\pi/12$ so you *did* get the right answer, after all.

Answer (score 4):

You're given the two numbers as a multiplication. Recall that $r_1e^{i\theta} \cdot r_2e^{i \phi} = r_1r_2e^{i(\theta + \phi)},$ which is to say that arguments get added together when multiplying.

Now, note that $\frac12 + \frac{\sqrt3}2$ has argument $\frac\pi3$, while $1 + i$ has argument $\frac\pi4$. The argument of their product, then, is $\frac\pi3 + \frac\pi4 = \frac{7\pi}{12}$.

You're not wrong when you say that the argument is $\tan^{-1}(-2 - \sqrt{3})$, because

\begin{align*}
\tan \frac{7\pi}{12} &= \tan \left(\frac\pi3 + \frac\pi4\right) \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{1 - (\sqrt{3})(1)} \\
&= \ldots \\
&= -2 - \sqrt{3}
\end{align*}
using the identity for $\tan(\alpha + \beta)$. It's just that it's not at all obvious that $\tan^{-1}(-2 - \sqrt{3}) = \frac{7\pi}{12}$, unlike for nicer angles whose tangents you've probably memorized!

So in this case, the "arguments get added" approach is the way to go.

Comment: It's not obvious that $\arctan(-2-\sqrt 3)$ is ... anything. But the square root makes me think its a "nice" ratio probably a rational multiple of pi.  So calculator time:  arctan(-2-3root(3) = -1.3089969389957471826927680763665.  And -1.3089969389957471826927680763665/pi = -0.41666666666666666666666666666667  which is clearly something divided by 3.  Easy to see it is -5/12 so the argument is $-5\pi/12$.  Which in positive terms is $7\pi/12$.

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair point -- the $\sqrt{3}$ does indicate it might have *something* to do with $\pi/3$ in some capacity.

Comment: It's not so much that $\sqrt 3$ indicate $\pi/3$ but that $\sqrt{n}$ indicates some sort of right triangle with integer sides... maybe. ($radius= r, r*cos = n \implies r*sin = \sqrt{r^2 - n^2}$).   In any event when you get a solution artan (whatever) it doesn't hurt to calculate it out, divide by pi and see if you get so nice rational*pi solution.

Comment: On a side note.  I kind of wish calculators had a single "display as $a\pi$" button or display mode.  It's kind of pointless to calculate in radians and to give a *decimal* value rather than an $x*pi$ value.  $.4166666666667\pi$ would be a *LOT* more useful than 1.3089969389957471826927680763665

Answer (score 0):

It is $\arctan(\sqrt{3})+\arctan(1)  = \frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: How do you mean? My book says that the angle is 7 pi/12

Comment: The answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ for the problem as it was originally posted when Hamid answered, as the $i$ was missing from the first factor.

Comment: That's true. I didn't mention the i but now it is edited

Answer (score 0):

I)  Tedious:  $z= (\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{3^{1/2}i}{2}) * (1+i)= (1/2 - \sqrt{3}/2) + (1/2 + \sqrt 3/2) i = $.  Arg($z$) = $\arctan (1+ \sqrt{3})/(1-\sqrt{3}) = -5\pi/12 = 7\pi/12$.

(To be fair, I made data entry errors the first *six* times I tried to enter this into a calculator.)

II) Easier (albeit it notation intimidating):  $\arg (1+i) = \pi/4$ so $i+1 = r*e^{\frac{\pi}4 i}$.  ($r = \sqrt 2$ but we don't give a toss.)  $\arg (1/2 + i\sqrt{3}/2) = \pi/3$ so $1/2 + i\sqrt{3}/2 = s*e^{\frac{\pi}3 i}$.  ($s = 1$ but we don't give a toss.)

So  $z= (\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{3^{1/2}i}{2}) * (1+i) = r*e^{\frac{\pi}4 i}*s*e^{\frac{\pi}3 i} = rse^{(\pi/3 + \pi/4)i}$ so $\arg(z) = \pi/3 + \pi/4 = 7\pi/12$.

====

Post Script: $\frac {1 + \sqrt 3}{1 - \sqrt 3}= \frac{(1 + \sqrt 3)^2}{1 - 3} = \frac {4 + 2\sqrt 3}{-2} = -2 - \sqrt 3$ so your first answer *was* absolutely correct.  Why did you doubt yourself?  Why did you assume $\tan^{-1}(-2 - \sqrt{3}) \ne 7\pi/12$?

Comment: I used a calculator.  Then I divided by pi to see if it had a "nice" answer.  (Actually, I figured the answer by adding the args.  Kept trying to use the calculator, made data entry errors six times and kept trying till I got the answer I wanted).  BTW.  If sin/cos = -2-\sqrt3 then there is a right triangle with a=1, b=2+\sqrt3, h = 8 + 4\sqrt3, so this is a triangle with 1 side = 1/4 the hypotenuse.  There's probably some geometry to get that this means angles of pi/12 and 5pi/12s but I can't figure it out off the top of my head.